# How to create a linear regression plot with distribution curves (e.g., normal distribution) that indicate the frequency at the X-Y axes in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to generate a linear regression plot with additional distribution curves on the X and Y axes in Python that indicate the distribution of values in each of these dimensions. See attached figure.

[image: Example of this type of figure]

I know how to create the linear plot, but have not been able to find a method to generate the distribution curves to appear on the axes themselves in Python.

Comment: You can create this plot with matplotlib. However, if you are not very familiar with this library, it might be easier to use seaborn as it has this plot type in its vocabulary: https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.jointplot.html#seaborn.jointplot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a good section of this on the matplotlib documentation, and with some modifications you can get something close-ish:

https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/scatter_hist.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-scatter-hist-py

The main component that I personally think is a great learning point is matplotlib's gridspec. It allows control of where the graphs are located which allows for stronger customization.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Fixing random state for reproducibility
np.random.seed(19680801)

# some random data
x = np.random.randn(1000)
y = np.random.randn(1000)


def scatter_hist(x, y, ax, ax_histx, ax_histy):
    # no labels
    ax_histx.tick_params(axis="x", labelbottom=False)
    ax_histy.tick_params(axis="y", labelleft=False)

    # the scatter plot:
    ax.scatter(x, y)

    # now determine nice limits by hand:
    binwidth = 0.25
    xymax = max(np.max(np.abs(x)), np.max(np.abs(y)))
    lim = (int(xymax/binwidth) + 1) * binwidth

    bins = np.arange(-lim, lim + binwidth, binwidth)
    ax_histx.hist(x, bins=bins)
    ax_histy.hist(y, bins=bins, orientation='horizontal')

# Start with a square Figure.
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6))
# Add a gridspec with two rows and two columns and a ratio of 1 to 4 between
# the size of the marginal axes and the main axes in both directions.
# Also adjust the subplot parameters for a square plot.
gs = fig.add_gridspec(2, 2,  width_ratios=(4, 1), height_ratios=(1, 4),
                      left=0.1, right=0.9, bottom=0.1, top=0.9,
                      wspace=0.00, hspace=0.00)
# Create the Axes.
ax = fig.add_subplot(gs[1, 0])
ax_histx = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 0], sharex=ax)
ax_histy = fig.add_subplot(gs[1, 1], sharey=ax)

# Remove Axis Lines
ax_histy.spines[['right', 'top', 'bottom']].set_visible(False)
ax_histx.spines[['right', 'top', 'left']].set_visible(False)

# Remove Ticks
ax_histy.set_xticks([])
ax_histx.set_yticks([])

# Draw the scatter plot and marginals.
scatter_hist(x, y, ax, ax_histx, ax_histy)
```

[image]